# JSON format issue

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit

I am new to web services and have GET working fine.  When I try to POST I am sending this JSON string:

```
{"frequency":"None","leader":"test@test.com"}
```

But the server is expecting this:

```
{ 
    "meta": 
       {"limit": 20, "total_count": 2}, 
    "objects": 
       [{"frequency": "None", "leader": "jsmith@gmail.com"},
        {"frequency": "None", "leader": "jsmith@gmail.com"}]
}
```

In my NewMeetingRK object I am trying to map to the "objects" as follows:

```
mgr.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

RKObjectMapping* newmtg = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];

    [newmtg mapKeyPath: @"frequency"     toAttribute:@"repeat"      ];
    [newmtg mapKeyPath: @"leader"     toAttribute:@"leader"      ];

RKObjectMapping* newmtgSerializeMapping = [newmtg inverseMapping];
    [mgr.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:newmtgSerializeMapping forClass:[NewMeetingRK class]];
[mgr.mappingProvider setMapping:newmtgSerializeMapping forKeyPath:@"objects"];

[mgr.router routeClass:[NewMeetingRK class] toResourcePath:@"" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

This isn't working.  I tried changing toResourcePath to @"/objects" but that didn't work either.  Any idea how to send the values to the second set of JSON values on the server?

---EDIT----

I was missing the array as @HotLicks pointed out - thanks.  But I still can't get my simple post with JSON values to work.
Instead of RKObjectManager can I do something simple with RKClient like this?

```
client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:[RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"https://appzute.appspot.com"]];
NSLog(@"I am your RKClient singleton : %@", [RKClient sharedClient]); 
client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;
[client setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableArray *meetingArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];  
[meetingArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         self.leaderEmail.text, @"leader", 
                         self.repeatLabel.text, @"frequency", 
                         nil]];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:meetingArray, @"objects", nil];

NSString *jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
NSLog (@"jsonString is: %@",jsonString);
[client post:@"/api/meeting/?format=json&username=testuser@test.com&api_key=sdf7asd87fs8df78sdf" params:jsonString delegate:self];
```

The value of jsonString looks perfect: {"objects":[{"leader":"me@me.com","frequency":"None"}]}
The issue is that params:jsonString is not valid, because it needs an object not a string.  But if I use params: jsonDictionary then I get this log file:
Sent RKRequest: objects[][leader]=me%40me.com&objects[][frequency]=None
I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:676 Status Code: 500

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't appear to be creating the array.  (I'm unfamiliar with that JSON kit.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfamiliar with that JSON toolkit, but generally what you'd do is create two dictionaries, one for each of your "objects", place them in an array (your "objects" array).  Then create a dictionary for your "meta" info.  Finally, create a dictionary to contain the "meta" info and the "objects" array.

JSON maps almost perfectly to NSDictionary/NSArray, so there's not really any need to use a toolkit that uses "wrapper" objects.

Comment: I don't want to post to "meta".  So should I create a dictionary with empty values for "meta"? Then do I create a dictionary with "meta" and "objects" array together to look something like this: {"Meta": {},"objects":{"frequency":"None","leader":"test@test.com"}}

Comment: Probably you'd leave "meta" out of the outer dictionary entirely (so the outer dictionary would only contain "objects").  But ask the guy who owns the server.

Comment: The server is setup fine, confirmed I should only be sending objects data, not meta.  Any idea why it's not mapping the key path?  Is there anything apparently wrong with my code?

Comment: Think about it.  You're building a structure of arrays and dictionaries to match the desired JSON structure, then you simply serialize that structure.  In JSON,  `{}` is a dictionary/"object", and `[]` is an array.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the meaning of [], that's fixed now, but I'm still missing something. Please see my updated question above.